How can i resolve error for two dependencies
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find com.shagi:material-datepicker:1.3.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/shagi/material-datepicker/1.3/material-datepicker-1.3.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/shagi/material-datepicker/1.3/material-datepicker-1.3.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/shagi/material-datepicker/1.3/material-datepicker-1.3.pom
- https://jitpack.io/com/shagi/material-datepicker/1.3/material-datepicker-1.3.pom
Required by:
project :app
Could not find oorg.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:4.0.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/oorg/sufficientlysecure/html-textview/4.0/html-textview-4.0.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/oorg/sufficientlysecure/html-textview/4.0/html-textview-4.0.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/oorg/sufficientlysecure/html-textview/4.0/html-textview-4.0.pom
- https://jitpack.io/oorg/sufficientlysecure/html-textview/4.0/html-textview-4.0.pom
Required by:
project :app


the URL to download  "oorg.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:4.0" is not working , check you're URL
